# How do I register classes by both interface and namespace with Windsor?

Tags: c#, castle-windsor

I'm trying to use Castle.Windsor (3.2.0.0) [convention based registration](http://stw.castleproject.org/Default.aspx?Page=Registering-components-by-conventions&NS=Windsor&AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1), but can't seem to figure out how to register classes implementing a particular interface *only* in a particular namespace.

e.g. what I really want to be able to write is something like this :

```
container.Register(Classes.FromThisAssembly()
                          .InNamespace("MyApp.EventHandlers")
                          .BasedOn(typeof(IHandlesEvent<>))
                          .WithServiceAllInterfaces()
```

But I get a warning that seems to imply what this will really do is register everything in the `EventHandlers` namespace and then everything in the current assembly that implements `IHandlesEvent<>`.

If I run the application this does indeed seem to be what happens. I don't want everything that implements that interface to be registered (for example, some of the implementing classes are Sagas, which need to be manually tracked) and I don't really want everything in that namespace registered.

I really don't want to register the event handlers individually, but I can't see from the Windsor documentation how to do what I need by convention. Is it possible?

Comment: I had never noticed this, v. interesting and surprising behavior. I would have thought this construct would internally resolve to a list of filters however it doesn't even look like this is the end result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm surprised too, but I could observe the behavior on Castle 3.2. `BasedOn` pushed a warning saying that it would reinitialize the registration: here is my sample code:

```
namespace WindsorTest
{
    public interface IHandlesEvent {}

    public interface IDontWantToBeRegistered {}

    namespace Select
    {
        public class SelectClass : IHandlesEvent { }
        public class DontRegisterMe : IDontWantToBeRegistered { }
    }

    namespace DontSelect
    {
        public class DontSelectClass: IHandlesEvent {}
    }


    internal class Program
    {
        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var container = new WindsorContainer();
            container.Register(Classes.FromThisAssembly()
                .InNamespace("WindsorTest.Select")
                .BasedOn<IHandlesEvent>()
                .WithServiceAllInterfaces()
                );
            foreach (var handler in container.ResolveAll<IHandlesEvent>())
            {
                Console.WriteLine(handler.GetType().Name);
            }

            foreach (var handler in container.ResolveAll<IDontWantToBeRegistered>())
            {
                Console.WriteLine(handler.GetType().Name);
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

It outputs `DontSelectClass` when ran.

However I found a way to start with the base class for your registration and refine it with the namespace afterwards. Just use:

```
container.Register(Classes.FromThisAssembly()
    .BasedOn<IHandlesEvent>()
    .If(t => t.Namespace == "WindsorTest.Select")
    .WithServiceAllInterfaces()
    );
```