# Castle windsor instances are registered as singleton even though explicitly declare per web request

Tags: inversion-of-control, castle-windsor

I am explicitly declaring my registerations as per web request lifecycle but they are still singletons.

this is a problem because my command handlers depend on an IDbConnection which is also registered per web request.

here is my registration code:

```
container.Register(
    Classes
        .FromAssemblyContaining<EcruiterCommands>()
        .BasedOn(typeof (ICommandHandler<>))
        .WithService.AllInterfaces()
        .LifestylePerWebRequest());
```

Comment: Try and show minimal code that reproduces the problem: start by registering commandhandlers only, then add code until you hit the problem. Then post the code :)

Comment: i don't want to nitpick but do you realize that by posting pictures of your registration code and not the code of the registration itself nobody could see your code, and thus nobody would have been able to help you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the issue, the culprit is this line:

```
.BasedOn(typeof (ICommandHandler<>))
```

it resets the registration.

Comment: Good catch. `BasedOn` is indeed dangerous as it silently restarts your configuration. I'm a bit angry at myself since I answered this very problem some time ago: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29142291/how-do-i-register-classes-by-both-interface-and-namespace-with-windsor/29143726#29143726

Comment: @samy thanks for your guidance. I tried to use interceptors as you said but I ran into another problem, if you're interested its here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29629645/castle-windsor-intercepter